# Can't create CSV file in Linux with JMeterPluginsCMD.sh after updating log4j files to 2.17

Tags: java, linux, csv, jmeter

A sample command is -

Jmeter-master:/tmp$ JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv /tmp/test.csv --input-jtl /tmp/jmeter.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

This works in Windows with the .bat file after updating the log4j files, but not with the .sh in Linux. I get the following error. Anyone else encountering this? BTW - It was working fine over a week ago in Linux, but stopped working at some point and don't recall making any breaking changes.

> ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/logging/LoggingUtils
> *** Problem's technical details go below *** Home directory was detected as: /opt/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/logging/LoggingUtils
> at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.(ReporterTool.java:17)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
> at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.getToolInstance(PluginsCMD.java:128)
> at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:50)
> at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> kg.apc.logging.LoggingUtils
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 14 more

Specific automation steps -

```
RUN curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/jmeter.tgz https://dlcdn.apache.org//jmeter/binaries/$JMETER_VERSION.tgz \
    && tar -C /opt -xzf /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && rm /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && chmod +w /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.7-sources.jar https://search.maven.org/classic/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter/0.7/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.7-sources.jar \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/3/file/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.tar.gz \
    && tar -C /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib -xzvf /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz --strip-components 1 mysql-connector-java-6.0.3/mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar \
    && rm /tmp/mysql-connector.tar.gz \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar https://jmeter-plugins.org/get \
    && curl -fsSL --compressed -o /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/cmdrunner-$CMDRUNNER_VERSION.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/$CMDRUNNER_VERSION/cmdrunner-$CMDRUNNER_VERSION.jar \
    && java -cp /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller \
    && /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh install-all-except jpgc-hadoop,jpgc-oauth,ulp-jmeter-gwt-plugin,ulp-jmeter-autocorrelator-plugin,ulp-jmeter-videostreaming-plugin \
    && sleep 2 \
    && /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh status
```

Error trying to do JMeterPluginsCMD.sh -

```
2021-12-30 13:03:12,008 WARN o.j.r.Plugin: Unable to load class: nz.co.breakpoint.jmeter.vizualizers.sshmon.SSHMonCollector
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/MonitoringResultsCollector
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.getJARPath(Plugin.java:202) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalledPlugin(Plugin.java:108) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalled(Plugin.java:97) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:86) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.getStaticManager(PluginManager.java:344) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.getAllPluginsStatus(PluginManager.java:370) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:72) [jmeter-plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.MonitoringResultsCollector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I believe this was working in Linux after updating the log4j files, and broke at some point after that for a yet unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` usually has something to do with the Runtime Environment Version. Try checking if both Java versions are equal.

If they **aren't equal**, try updating/downgrading your version on the Linux system accordingly.

If they **are equal**, try checking for missing libraries.

Comment: The Jenkins pipeline automation sets the JRE version. This has remained version 11 before and after this problem was observed. It's less clear (to me) where/how the automation is picking up the Linux version, but will see if I can find that. It's not readily obvious that I can se.

Comment: BTW - How would I know if a library went "missing"? Again, this is all being done via automation and has not changed (to my knowledge), other than me replacing 2.11 log4j files with 2.17 ones.

Comment: Had the same issue with a local Jenkins server, which is much easier to work with than the automation via AWS. Updating JMeter did of course not get the plugins that had been in place, so I didn't have the cmdrunner-x.x.jar or the jmeter-plugins-cmd-x.x.jar. That fixed the local Jenkins jobs. Now I just need to see what the differences are in the automation servers spun up in AWS, but feel like I'm at least on the right track.

Comment: So the problem is that I'm actually not getting the JMeterPluginsCMD.sh file on the AWS server. The command to put it there (/opt/$JMETER_VERSION/bin/PluginsManagerCMD.sh) is failing and not sure why. I will add the error info to the end of the original post since it's too large to fit here.

Comment: I broke out the java -cp command from the one that installs the plugins so I could see the output of each separately. The command doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't lay down the JMeterPluginsCMD.sh file.

Comment: I was able to do the "java -cp /opt/$JMETER_VERSION/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller" command manually on the server (docker container in this case) and it threw no errors, but it also didn't put the JMeterPluginsCMD.sh file in the JMeter /bin folder. I have no idea why I'm not getting the .sh file, but that is obviously why the JMeterPluginsCMD.sh command is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what do you mean by "updating log4j files to 2.17", the error you're getting is about missing [`jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter) .jar in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

If you prefer manual .jar libraries manipulation you could download the version you like the most to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation, on next JMeter restart or running the command-line graph generator tool the error should go away.

However I would recommend:

- Orchestrating JMeter Plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) instead of doing it manually
- Using the l[atest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) instead of trying to upgrade individual components

Comment: We recently had to update log4j files on all servers that had them due to the security issue with log4j. JMeter uses log4j. It may be coincidence but the problems I'm seeing happened around that time. There is now a JMeter version that has the updated log4j files, but now that has a different error/issue.

Comment: I placed jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.7-sources.jar in the /lib folder, which is in the path. Same problem. Is this the proper missing file?

Comment: I will add the specific automation steps I'm using to the original post, if that helps. They were too big to add as a comment.

Comment: I have never told you to put "sources" jar to "/lib" folder, please address these questions to the person who provided you with these instructions

Answer (score 0):

The reason I can't create a CSV file is because that is done using JMeterPluginsCMD.sh, which doesn't exist. The command that is supposed to create the JMeterPluginsCMD.sh and JMeterPluginsCMD.bat files is not working.

It's not throwing an error that I can see, but it also is not creating the .sh or .bat files in the /bin folder.

The command that's supposed to do that as far as I can tell is -

```
java -cp jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.JMeterPluginsCMDInstaller
```

I'm closing out this as answered and will open another issue if I can't figure out why I'm not getting these sh and bat files.

Doing this through the GUI is not an option in this case as the test is being set-up and executed via automation.